# how to query using ... olivere / elastic?

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm trying to search the document on elasticsearch with github.com/olivere/elastic, but I'm not able to create the query ...

I need results...

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "recipient_id": 111
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But in Code...

```
import "github.com/olivere/elastic"

boolQuery := elastic.NewBoolQuery()
mustQueries := make([]elastic.Query, 0)
mustQueries = append(mustQueries, elastic.NewMatchQuery("recipient_id", 11))
boolQuery.Must(mustQueries...)

src, _ := boolQuery.Source()
PrintQuery(src)
```

```
func PrintQuery(src interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("*****")
    data, err := json.MarshalIndent(src, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Results

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "match": {
        "recipient_id": {
          "query": 11
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Are you leaving this...
Please could you help me ?

here's my code where I'm doing the query

```
func Search() {
    client, err := GetClient()
    if err != nil { panic(err) }

    boolQuery := elastic.NewBoolQuery()
    mustQueries := make([]elastic.Query, 0)
    mustQueries = append(mustQueries, elastic.NewMatchQuery("recipient_id", 111))
    boolQuery.Must(mustQueries...)

    searchResult, err := client.Search().
        Index(NameIndex).
        Type("_search").
        Query(boolQuery).
        Do(context.Background())

    fmt.Println(searchResult)
    fmt.Println(searchResult)
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the shown results from? What issue do you have actually *executing* the query? Please show the full relevant code and an errors/results you get.

Comment: @Adrian, when I run I have no errors ... But I made a print in the query ...

Comment: I have error...
cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field SearchHits.hits.total of type int64

Comment: I don't think that error has anything to do with the first part of the question regarding `boolQuery`. It sounds like maybe your elastic library and elastic server versions aren't compatible? What version of the library and what version of ElasticSearch are you using?

Comment: yes, the problem was the version ... it was in the api 6 version and my elastic was with 7

Answer (score 0):

I interpret two questions from your post

1. why must query contains an object item instead of an array item?
2. why match query's format is different?

*Answer to Question 1*

In your following code snippet, you have placed only one match query in the must queries.

```
mustQueries := make([]elastic.Query, 0)
mustQueries = append(mustQueries, elastic.NewMatchQuery("recipient_id", 111))
```

hence the match element contains an object item as shown below

```
"must": {
   "match": {
      "recipient_id": {
         "query": 11
       }
    }
 }
```

If you place one more match query in the must queries, you will get an array item. The following code snippet results a match element with an array item.

```
mustQueries := make([]elastic.Query, 0)
mustQueries = append(mustQueries, elastic.NewMatchQuery("recipient_id", 111))
mustQueries = append(mustQueries, elastic.NewMatchQuery("recipient_name", 'tom'))
```

The above code snippet results the following query

```
"must": [
   {
      "match": {
         "recipient_id": {
            "query": 11
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "match": {
         "recipient_name": {
            "query": "tom"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

*Answer to Question 2*

The NewMatchQuery(...,...) API produces full text match query. This is the reason, you get the following match query

```
"match": {
   "recipient_id": {
      "query": 11
   }
}
```

instead of the following one.

```
"match": {
   "recipient_id": 11
}
```

Finally,
the query what you expect and the query what code produces fetches same results.